# MVC3 - EF4: One DbContext for all Repositories and ViewModels - UnitOfWork?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1, unit-of-work

I'm totally stuck.

- I've got two Controller: "Customer" and "Address". Both have the fields CustomerRepository and AddressRepository.
- There are two ViewModels: CustomerViewModel and AddressViewModel. They also have the fields CustomerRepository and AddressRepository. (And also a parameterless constructor since they are parameters within the edit and create methods)
- The Repositories themselves have a DbContext object from my Entities.

Now I'm running into one problem after another. I think I should have only ONE DbContext to share with all of my classes (Repositories AND ViewModels). And I think UnitOfWork is the solution. But I have no clue how to use that.

I currently tried to create a DbContext within the controllers constructor and pass it to every single object requiring it. But even that doesn't work.

If code is necessary, I will post it.

Comment: ViewModel should not have reference to repository! That is responsibility of controller to use repository and fill view model with all relevant data.

Comment: What didn't work when you created DbContext in controller's constructor? Btw. this is usually solved by dependency injection.

Comment: Are you using an IoC container? i.e. Structuremap, Autofac ??? This could be why your controllers constructor injection is not working. Try using NuGet and installing StructureMap.MVC3

Comment: Oh...I'm filling the ViewModels via Repository with some lists etc.. I will change that first, today. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Couple of things to know:

### 1.  Unit of Work

Unit of Work is not necessarily some kind of implementation for `IUnitOfWork`. It is just a pattern that might be applied in many ways. First, and foremost - you should understand what is it for before actually using it and overcomplicate things around. Moreover, EF Code-First DbContext API's `DbContext` **is** a kind of `Unit of Work` pattern. Your `IDbSet<>`s are your repositories. Don't try to abstract from your ORM, start with simplest possible thing.

### 2. DbContext injection

For the beginning, just inject the DbContext to your Controller with constructor injection. Don't forget to setup the IoC container of choice and wire up the MVC's `DependencyResolver`. Your controller could be look like (example also contains AutoMapper usage example, see next point about ViewModels for that):

```
public CustomerController : Controller
{
    public CustomerController(MyDbContext data, IMappingEngine mapper)
    {
        Data = data;
        Mapper = mapper;
    }

    public MyDbContext Data { get; set; }

    public IMappingEngine Mapper { get; set; }

    // Other controller code
}
```

### 3. View Models

This, again, is a pattern that is so easily implementable - just have your `CustomerViewModel` and use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org) to easily transform your `Customer` to `CustomerViewModel` so that you can do it like this:

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
    var customer = Data.Customers.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);

    if (customer == null)
        return new HttpNotFoundResult();

    return View(Mapper.Map<CustomerViewModel>(customer));
}
```

You can interrogate the AutoMapper's website on how to wire it up and make it running.
Notice that you don't get the ViewModel from DbContext directly. You obtain an "entity" instead which then transformed to appropriate View Model.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, I tried removing the repositories from my ViewModels and just create the DbContext within the controller which then uses this reference for the repositories constructors. This works well since I've only got a few controllers and repositories. Now, I don't know which answer I should mark as "accepted". Yours (wehich I didn't try, yet) or Mystere Mans.

Comment: @Sleepwalker, heh, I can't advise on that :) Neither answer is end-to-end solution (and never intended to be) but both direct you to some further discovery and patterns/methods to do something. Mark whichever is more useful to you!

Answer (score 2):

Your ViewModels should not have references to the DbContext or repositories.  ViewModels should be largely stupid.  It is the job of the controller (or a service called by the controller) to populate the ViewModels with the data the View needs.

Unit Of work is a good pattern, and one you should use.. but the patern is not a fix for your problem.  Your problem is that you are making your view have too much knowledge of your data model.

Answer (score 0):

I currently do the following:
One injected IUnitOfWork using unity to inject into my controllers.

IUnitOfWork implements IContext.

IContext contains IDbSet Customers and IDbSet
The concrete implementation of IContext implements DbContext.

My controllers reference a service, the service uses the IUnitOfWork.
If you use a repository, then simply use a single IContext injected into your controller (or IUnitOfWork which is fairly easy to add on top)

This way I have one context per lifetime of the request and then it's disposed. If you want more code let me know I'll see what I can post up here.

Comment: Hi Adam, can you please share an example to make available the context to the controller, service and controller's Helpers (function that for example populates the dropdown lists). I'm starting a project and I don't want to have to transport the context everywhere. Thanks